# How can I optimize this query PostGIS

Tags: postgis, postgresql

I have 2 spatial tables:
Streets: linestrings of streets from a country (more than 3 million)
Portals: points of adress from a country (around 18 million)

I need to move each point to the closest linestring matching 2 conditions, the query to do that is like this:

```
update portals pt
     set geom = (select st_closestpoint(s.streets_geom, pt.portal_geom)
                from streets s
                where pt.field1 = s.field2
                and pt.field3 = s.field3
                order by pt.portal_geom <-> s.streets_geom
                limit 1)
```

So far the query works well in tests but when I do it for all the data, it takes too long (several days) I have spatial index on both geometries.
How can I improve the query to do it faster? I can't figure it out

EDIT: Explain of the query
[image]

Comment: do you have indexes on `pt.field1, pt.field3` and `s.field2, s.field3`?

Comment: please add the output of `explain` on the query

Comment: @JGH No, that columns don't have indexes, should I add them?

Comment: @IanTurton Edited with the explain

Answer (score 1):

The query plan shows that for each row to be updated in `pt` (`p` in the plan), another seq scan is done on the other table `s` (`v` in the plan), which basically means that 18M * 3M = 54M rows are scanned, which has to take some time.

Add an index on the filtering key on the 2nd table (`s` / `v`), and don't forget to run `vacuum analyze` on it before re-running the query